# Showing only part of webview on Android App

Tags: android, webview

Say I have a web view in my android app on android studio, is there a way for me to only show a part of the web view.  For example, only a select few items from a list of items on eBay - hiding the website search bar, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a workaround like this, use a networking library ex: ion android, volley etc,.. and

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=red+led&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=redled
```

request the result as a get call and iterate through the HTML results to aquire image links titles and other data. or try inspecting the network calls for the search facility. I couldn't find any API endpoints but you might find. iterating through the HTML and reading is better cause you can have your own native listviews. but remember this is against google's and eBay's policies. better for learning.try the link with postmen with and without '**preview**' , if you find this somewhat useful please consider a vote or as the answer for someone else to find it easily, thanks, good luck!

[image]
you can load the URL in a webview and inject JavaScript
[Check this](https://medium.com/@filipe.batista/inject-javascript-into-webview-2b702a2a029f) and you can use javascript to do get the data like

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

this will return every node with above-mentioned classes, for example

```
class="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"
```

this is how ebay configured their searched item results title, you can check that in the image. and [Try this](http://rapidprogrammer.com/android-how-to-call-native-java-methods-from-webview-javascript) with this you can pass all the data read by javascript to java method easily. all those reading and filtering javascript functions can be injected. the best practice is to inject all the necessary JS functions at once. you can search by changing that URL parameter **_nkw**. for this operation, no need a real webview you can initialize a webview without inflating to activity layout .xml. ex: WebView webview = new WebView(); and continue with that webview object. you can experiment.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, could you expand on what you mean by trying the link with postmen and without preview?